# How to use font-weight in vue?

Tags: vuetify.js

I have already installed vuetify and use the its `font-weight-` class

Here is my code below:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <p class="font-weight-black">Black text.</p>
    <p class="font-weight-bold">Bold text.</p>
    <p class="font-weight-medium">Medium weight text.</p>
    <p class="font-weight-regular">Normal weight text.</p>
    <p class="font-weight-light">Light weight text.</p>
    <p class="font-weight-thin">Thin weight text.</p>
    <p class="font-italic">Italic text.</p>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

My question is why **medium**, **normal**, **light**, and **thin** were all same font-weight (see picture below) compare to its example from [vuetify font-weight](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/text-and-typography/#font-weights-and-italics). Anybody knows how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using your browser's _Elements_ console to inspect the styles applied to each paragraph?

Comment: Have you [installed the Roboto font](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#font-installation)?

Comment: They do not look same to me.

Comment: Assuming you're using Chrome ~ https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css. It's very similar for Firefox as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by importing fonts to my **app.scss**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900');
```

Or just append the code below on html file

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
```

helpful [link1](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/4444), [link2](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/#font-installation)

Comment: it's better to add the font in the public.html :)